# 7-Zip API abort progress

Tags: delphi, 7zip, lzma

I'm using [d7zip](https://libraries.io/github/geoffsmith82/d7zip) for my project, everything worked very well as check list, compression, decompression, progress bar...

But I do not know how to abort compression or decompression. I checked the source code [LZMA SDK](http://www.7-zip.org/sdk.html) but did not find anything.

Anything that can help me easier?

Comment: Please show [mcve]

Comment: Thank you, problem are solved

Comment: I hope you have learnt the importance of providing detail in the question. As it stands this question can have no value to future readers.

Comment: Looks like people are voting bandwagon...

Comment: Or maybe the question is actually poor, and the votes would be reversed if you would improve it in an edit. You decide.

Comment: Why nearly 40 first views with 0 down vote but 43 views with 3 vote down

Comment: Why don't you improve the question? Ask yourself how it will help future visitors in its current form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your progress callback, try returning an error `HRESULT` value instead of `S_OK` or `S_FALSE`.

Comment: I tried to return to `ERROR_CANCELLED` and it did nothing more

Comment: @nguyentu Try to use E_ABORT.

Comment: Tried, nothing is executed except the finally block

Comment: @nguyentu: `ERROR_CANCELLED` is not an `HRESULT` value, `E_ABORT` is. `HRESULT` success values are positive, error values are negative. Regular Win32 error codes are positive. If you want to return a Win32 error code, wrap it with `HRESULT_FROM_WIN32()`, eg: `Result := HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(ERROR_CANCELLED);`

Comment: @nguyentu: Did you verify that *any* of the callbacks are actually being called during compression/decompression?  Please show your actual code. If the callbacks are being called, but returning an error code from them is not working, then I have to think that either d7zip is not hooking them up correctly internally (more likely), or 7zip is ignoring them (less likely).

Comment: sorry because it was not clear. It work but nothing is executed after the process is canceled except the finally block but I want the thread is continued

Comment: There is likely an exception being thrown when an operation fails.  Wrap the operation in a `try/except` block and move on.

Comment: @nguyentu, So what was the problem/solution?

Comment: @kobik my problem I don't know how to abort the process of compression or decompression, my solution return `E_ABORT` on callback